# Android volley post request using name value pairs

Tags: android, hashmap, http-post, android-volley, basicnamevaluepair

I am using the [volley](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html) library for making a post request to the server. This library uses `Map<String, String>` for the post parameters. My problem is want to have multiple values for the same key, which can be using `NameValuePairs` but it cannot be used with volley. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

try override below method, it is from source code:

```
/**
 * Returns the raw POST or PUT body to be sent.
 *
 * @throws AuthFailureError in the event of auth failure
 */
public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
    Map<String, String> params = getParams();
    if (params != null && params.size() > 0) {
        return encodeParameters(params, getParamsEncoding());
    }
    return null;
}
```

**Returns the raw POST or PUT body to be sent.**

so override the `getBody()` with your parameter.

Comment: So, how will it help me to have entries with duplicate keys? Can you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: override `getBody()` construct your `NameValuePairs` then convert it to `byte array`, or construct something like `"key=value1&key=value2"` then convert it to byte array.